# Load KML check box

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

I'm using this sample code and I am confused on what the following parts do and where they come from. I do not understand the `(\'red\')` portion of the onclick or the `+ file +` either. I am trying to change this to `createNetworkLink` and using my own tester.kml. When I change the `+ file +` it breaks.

```
    var currentKmlObjects = {
      'red': null,
    };

addSampleUIHtml(
        '<h2>Toggle KML Files:</h2>' +
        '<input type="checkbox" id="kml-red-check" onclick="toggleKml(\'red\');"/><label for="kml-red-check">Red Placemarks</label><br/>'
      );

     function loadKml(file) {
      var kmlUrl = 'http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/' +
        'examples/static/' + file + '.kml';

      // fetch the KML
      google.earth.fetchKml(ge, kmlUrl, function(kmlObject) {
        // NOTE: we still have access to the 'file' variable (via JS closures)

        if (kmlObject) {
          // show it on Earth
          currentKmlObjects[file] = kmlObject;
          ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        } else {
          // bad KML
          currentKmlObjects[file] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

"red" is only a example. If the kml you want to load is "mydoc.kml", then replace red by mydoc. Replace http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/' + 'examples/static/ by the location where your file is on the web. Don't touch +file+. You must have something like that:
'http://myadress.com/file/' + file + '.kml'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definition of the `loadkml` function.

```
function loadKml(file) { ...
```

the word `file` is simply a parameter, whatever you pass to the function will be represented by `file` within the scope of the function.

If ones calls `loadKml("FOO")` then the `kmlUrl` within the function would be equal to

`http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/static/FOO.kml`

Now, you don't show your `toggleKml` function- but it too looks to accept a single parameter just like `loadkml` does. It will look something like.

```
function toggleKml(file) { ...
```

So, when you click `toggleKml("red");` is called, passing the value `"red"` into it. So, within the scope of the method the word `file` will have the value `red`, if you called `toggleKml("orange");` - the word `file` will have the value `orange` - and so on.